# How can I apply a line break formula to a set of specified cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know you can just do alt + enter to insert a line break but I have a whole worksheet that has come with cells in the following format

word,word,word

I need all of them in the format

Word

Word

Word

Is there a way I can highlight all cells and apply a rule such that anything in the format word,word,word is automatically converted to

Word

Word

Word

Im not sure if you can apply a formatting rule like this I've just been inserting the line breaks manually using alt + enter

Comment: Do the resulting cells need to be one above the other? If not, look at Text to Column

Comment: yeah i need them to stay in the same cell and above one another in the same order

Comment: Use `Ctrl+H` to open the _Find and Replace_ dialog box.  Find the `,` and replace with Alt+0010.  i.e. Press Alt and enter 0010 on the number pad (not the keys along the top) to replace with a line break character.  If 0010 doesn't work try 0013.  Make sure wrap text is turned on.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.